# assigning the value of a 2d matrix to an variable

Tags: c++

I have a 3x3 matrix which is not sorted.

After sorting the 3x3 matrix in ascending or descending order I want to store the median value in an integer variable (`int med`).

As my matrix is having odd number of elements I know that every time the median value will be `matrix[1][1]`, so I have basically written like this:

```
int med = matrix[1][1];
```

Though I get no compile time error in Visual Studio while running the application for median, I got this below run time error:

```
"#2 run time check failure..the stack around variable matrix[][] is corrupted..
```

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <mtip.h>
#define MAX 3

int medianfilter_MIF(HMTIPMOD hMod ,Dataset_byte *in,Dataset_byte **out,int th) 
{
    if(!in)
    {
        mmsg_ReportError("Missing input!");
        return MRV_FAILURE;
    }

    *out = (Dataset_byte*)md_DatasetClone((Dataset*)in, DST_SAME);
    if(!*out)
    {
        mmsg_ReportError("Could not clone image!");
        return MRV_FAILURE;
    }


    BYTE *pin = DATA_PTR(in);
    BYTE *pout = DATA_PTR(*out);
    int d_w = NX(in); 
    int d_h = NY(in);
    int mask2d_int[MAX][MAX];
    int *element;
    int temp;

    for (int i = 1; i < d_w - 1; i++){  
        for (int j = 1; j < d_h - 1; j++){
            int temp = VAL2(in,i,j);
            mmsg_ReportError("the value of temp is: %d ",temp);
            for (int p = i - 1; p < i + 2; p++){
                for (int q = j - 1; q < j + 2; q++){
                    mask2d_int[p][q]=VAL2(in,p,q);
                    mmsg_ReportError("the value of mask2d_int[p][q] : %d ",mask2d_int[p][q]);
                }
            }


    for (element = &mask2d_int[0][0]; element <= &mask2d_int[MAX-1][MAX-1]; element ++) {
                 if (*element > *(element + 1)) {
               *element ^= *(element + 1); /* exclusive or swap */
               *(element + 1) ^= *element;
               *element ^= *(element + 1);
               }
        msg_ReportError("the value of element after swapping is %d ",element);
            }
            int med = mask2d_int[1][1];
            mmsg_ReportError("the value of median is: %d ",med);
            if ((temp - med) < th){
                *pout = temp;
                mmsg_ReportError("the value of *pout before is %d ",*pout);
                }
            else{
                *pout = med;
                mmsg_ReportError("the value of *pout after is %d ",*pout);
                }
            ++pout;
            }
        }
    return MRV_SUCCESS;
}


int medianfilter_MDF(HMTIPMOD hMod)
{
    INPUT_DATASET("Input image", 0, 0, DST_BYTE, CONN_REQUIRED);
    OUTPUT_DATASET("Output image", 0, 0, DST_BYTE, 0);
    CONTROL_INT_SLIDER("threshold:",30,0,255);
    return MRV_SUCCESS;
}

REGISTER_MTIP_MODULE("Median Filter", medianfilter_MDF, medianfilter_MIF, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Please post the code of the whole function. The problem is likely not on this line.

Comment: i have added the entire code now .Could you please try to find out the problem..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

```
for (element = &mask2d_int[0][0]; element <= &mask2d_int[MAX-1][MAX-1]; element ++) {
                                          ^^
                 if (*element > *(element + 1)) {
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You loop while `element <= &mask2d_int[MAX-1][MAX-1]` which means element runs up to and including the last int, which you then compare with the "next" int (which doesn't exist), and possibly swap.

The bytes after your multidimensional array contain a "magic value" put their by your compiler (which is probably generating a debug build). Swapping the last int in the array with the bytes after the array trashes this value, causing the error you are seeing.

Changing the for loop to

```
for (element = &mask2d_int[0][0]; element < &mask2d_int[MAX-1][MAX-1]; element ++) {
                                          ^
```

should do the trick.

If all you want is to get it working - then I've said my say - But I notice that the only reason you sort the matrix is to get the median, and that you've tagged this question "c++" which means that there are some easier ways of doing this if you are interested.